# Unable to commit file through svn, server sent truncated HTTP response body

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, svn, apache-http-server, redmine

I have my own VPS, on which I want to run a simple SVN + chiliproject setup. I have re-installed SVN, CHILI and the OS several times, and it always works for a couple of hours/days and then it just stops working. Well, everything works, except I can't upload any files. Committing directories seems to work just fine, but when I try to commit a file it breaks.

I have an error log file, which gives me the following text when I try to commit something

```
x.x.x.x - -     [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "OPTIONS    /project HTTP/1.1" 200 149
x.x.x.x - -     [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "PROPFIND   /project HTTP/1.1" 207 346
x.x.x.x - -     [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "MKACTIVITY /project/!svn/act/c11d45ac-86b6-184a-ac5a-9a1105d64563 HTTP/1.1" 401 345
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "MKACTIVITY /project/!svn/act/c11d45ac-86b6-184a-ac5a-9a1105d64563 HTTP/1.1" 201 262
x.x.x.x - -     [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "PROPFIND   /project HTTP/1.1" 207 236
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "CHECKOUT   /project/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 201 271
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "PROPPATCH  /project/!svn/wbl/c11d45ac-86b6-184a-ac5a-9a1105d64563/1 HTTP/1.1" 207 267
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "CHECKOUT   /project/!svn/ver/1 HTTP/1.1" 201 271
x.x.x.x - -     [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "HEAD       /project/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:01:46 +0200] "PUT        /project/!svn/wrk/c11d45ac-86b6-184a-ac5a-9a1105d64563/index.html HTTP/1.1" 201 269
x.x.x.x - admin [19/Oct/2013:00:02:04 +0200] "DELETE     /project/!svn/act/c11d45ac-86b6-184a-ac5a-9a1105d64563 HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

So it seems that it PUTs the file (test.html) correctly, and somehow somewhere something is wrong (file permissions are alright, when I purposely stated that they are wrong, it gave me errors, which is expected, and they were about the file permissions being incorrect.

The odd thing is that files won't get added, but directories are fine. I also have enough storage left on my machine.

What I should note, perhaps, is that I use Ubuntu 12.04.3 with ruby 1.9.3, mysql 14.14 and I have it set up that Chiliproject handles the authentication and authorization for the project. It works, because I can commit directories and read it all correctly, though I can't upload files.

Help would really be appreciated, as I don't know what on earth is going on with this 'truncated http response body'. I tried to read them with wireshark, but it gave me basically the same information.

With regards,

**Ps.** I asked this question at serverfault.com as well, yet someone suggested that I should ask it here. Because I don't know where I have to ask it, I asked it at both.